# Login page returning 404

Tags: bug, login, stackexchange.com

Whenever I attempt to login, I end up getting redirected back to the homepage and not be logged in. I am getting a 404 error:

https://stackexchange.com/users/login/universal/request Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What site are you logging in on? In what browser?

Comment: I did some digging through traffic logs. Looks like you logged in here on Meta, then went to stackexchange.com and that's where you weren't logged in. Is that correct? If not, definitely gonna need more information here. But if yes, the actual problem looks to be that you don't have a user profile on stackexchange.com (which is normal - how se.com is set up in that respect is kinda convoluted) and we're not handling that correctly. I'll dig more tomorrrow.

Comment: Google chrome, I click login, then click log in via Stack Exchange, It spins for a while but then just redirects me back to the home page with that 404 error in the console.

Comment: on stackexchange.com? Any chance you could add some screenshots of what you see? I'm fairly certain the 404 is irrelevant - you're already logged in on *.stackexchange.com (which is how you're posting here), but stackexchange.com itself is a separate codebase and has slightly different login mechanics under some circumstances.

Comment: Here is an album depicting the process flow, note that after being redirected back to home back I am still not logged in. And I haven't been prompted for username or password.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GsRrC

Comment: Here is the stack trace

Comment: https://imgur.com/yhrYGyk

Comment: Did you wait for the [form](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Be0K.png) to load? After clicking the "Stack Exchange" button, there is a login form. I see the loading dots in your screenshot, but I can't tell if you used the form. The browser devtools on that page could give a hint as to the problem there.