# Login page 404 still happening!! Cannot login on stack exhcange

Tags: bug

[Login page returning 404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/login-page-returning-404)

This question never got answered, I wanted to ask a new question on stack overflow, I had forgotten I had this issue months ago.

The problem is still happening, it prevents me from logging in, as after entering my credentials I get redirected back to the home page in a not logged in state, upon checking console I see a 404 has happened (may be unrelated issue though).

Comment: That question never got answered, even after posting screenshots.

Comment: Just because it didn't get answered doesn't mean it's not a duplicate.

Comment: You should continue to follow up with the previous question, rather than posting a duplicate.  It looked like you had a Mod's attention, but there was no follow-up.  Try responding to direct comments with @ to make sure that he knows that you've replied.

Comment: If you can't log in to Stack Overflow it's a different problem. That other question is about http://stackexchange.com which is **NOT** Stack Overflow. Anyway, if you have browsers plugins/extensions (e.g. AdBlocker, HTTPS Everywhere etc.) try to disable them, they tend to mess things up.